# JS window.open method in Safari browser

Tags: javascript, ios, safari

I've faced a problem with JS window.open method in Safari browser:

> The standard window.open() JavaScript method cannot be used to open a
>   new tab and window from a global HTML file or an extension bar.
>   https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/WorkingwithWindowsandTabs/WorkingwithWindowsandTabs.html

So, I'm trying this code instead:

```
safari.self.browserWindow.openTab(myLink);
```

But I get an error:

> index.html:199 Uncaught ReferenceError: safari is not defined

(in google chrome developer tools iPhone emulations, it doesn't work on real iPhones either)

Edit, here is more context:

```
var link = 'http://www.example.com/';
something.addEventListener("touchend", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    if(navigator.userAgent) {
        safari.self.browserWindow.openTab(link);
    }
});
```

Why `safari.self.browserWindow.openTab(myLink);` doesn't work in Safari?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: The question is: why "safari.self.browserWindow.openTab(myLink);" doesn't work in Safari, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use Like this:
safari.self.tab.dispatchMessage('openurlNewTab', 'http://www.example.com/');

//the message name 'openurlNewTab' is arbitrary//

Comment: Doesn't work: var link = 'http://www.example.com/';
this.addEventListener("touchend", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    if(navigator.userAgent) {
        safari.self.tab.dispatchMessage('openurlNewTab', link);
    }
});